# Issues with evaluating expressions from user input

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a recursive definition that reads and execute user expressions, such as `(3 + 5)`. Everything is working, except of one problem with the arithmetic symbol.

I managed to replicate the error in a simpler example:

```
(define v '(1 + 3))

((cadr v) 2 4)
```

The `(cadr v)` is the `+` symbol, but for some reason the procedure can't be executed on the two arguments that followed. Am I missing something?

Comment: The symbol `'+` is not the same as the function `+`; use `eval` as explained by Oscar and soulcheck to turn the former into the latter.

Comment: I don't think 'eval' is the right choice here--I blather more below.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's because

```
(cadr v)
```

returns `'+` not `+` (literal `+` not a `+` function).

You need to evaluate it before applying it to arguments.

This should work:

```
((eval (cadr v)) 2 4)
 ^evaluates the '+ to +
```

**edit**
This worked in racket in interactive mode.

I'm not really sure what's the difference, but made it work in r5rs mode in racket (a script):

```
#lang r5rs

;required by r5rs
(define user-initial-environment (scheme-report-environment 5))

(define v '(1 + 2))

;eval expects a quoted expression
;(it seems that if it's a function it has to have arguments too)
;and evaluation environment.
((eval (cadr v)  user-initial-environment) 2 4)
```

Comment: I tried using eval, but it doesn't work as I hoped. Is it because I set my language to R5RS?

Comment: I got a new error, procedure meval: expects 2 arguments, given 1: +

Comment: @OrieStone sorry i tried it in racket and clojure. eval works differently there.

Comment: I also use DrRacket... what's going on?

Comment: @OrieStone Racket's `eval` function takes two arguments as you can read [here](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/eval.html). The second argument is a namespace that eval uses to get its bindings. If you run soulcheck's example in DrRacket, you'll need to supply the optional namespace argument (`(make-base-namespace)` should work) unless you're in the interactions area.

Comment: Recommending `eval` is a bad advice; using the r5rs language is a bad idea; combining the two can be disastrously confusing for newbies.

Comment: @EliBarzilay yeah, i can see why r5rs can be a bad idea, but is there any way to avoid using eval in this case?

Comment: @soulcheck: Well, the first instinct should be using plain values (list `+` vs `'+`), if that's not enough then the next step is macros.  However, "reads and execute user expressions" does suggest using `eval`, and when a newbie wants that, then its best to ask why first, since in most cases there's no need for it.  In rare cases where that's really needed, a macro with the `read-eval-print-loop` function would be easier to manage.  `eval` should be used only if all else fails, but that requires [understanding it](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html).

Comment: So I guess scheme-report-environment 5 is crucial for eval in DrRacket R5RS. I wish I was told about that in class. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that the list you've constructed contains the symbol plus, rather than the function plus.

At its heart, this is the same reason that '(a b) returns a list of two symbols, rather than signalling an unbound identifier error; the quote starts a term in a "data language" where legal identifiers are interpreted as symbols, rather than as variable references.

The question, of course, is what you should do about it.  Some here have suggested using 'eval'; this is probably a bad idea, for reasons that I think Matthew Flatt captures elegantly in [his blog post on the topic](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html).

Instead, you should probably write a simple mapping function. Here's the way I'd write it. If you use my code in an assignment, be sure to credit me :).

```
#lang racket

;; a mapping from symbols to operators
(define operator-hash
  (hash '+ +
        '- -
        '* *))
;; ... and whatever other operators you want.

;; example of using it:
(hash-ref operator-hash '+) ;; ==> +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(define v '(1 + 3))

(let ((operator (eval (cadr v)))
      (operand1 (car v))
      (operand2 (caddr v)))
  (apply operator (list operand1 operand2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way with `eval` in Guile:

```
(define (infix-eval v)
   (eval (list (cadr v)(car v)(caddr v))
         (interaction-environment)))

> (infix-eval '(1 + 2))
3
```

Rather than using `interaction-environment`, you could supply another environment for evaluation, where you could also define some other symbols not found in standard Scheme, so that expressions like `(7 % 3)` and `(2 ^ 6)` would also work.